# Artifact naming convention

Tags: maven, naming-conventions, osgi, artifact

We're doing a big project on OSGi and adding some commons modules. There's some discussion about naming the artifact.

So, one possibility when naming the module is for example:

`cmns-definitions` (for *common definitions*), another is `cmns-definition`, still another is `cmns-def`. This has some effect also on the package name. Now it's 
`xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.commons.definitions`, if changing to `cmns-def` it would be `xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.commons.def`.

Inside this package will be classes like enums and other definitions to be used throughout the system.

I personally lean to `cmns-definitions` since there's not only 1 definition inside the package. Other people point out that `java.util` doesn't have only 1 utility there for example. Still, `java.util` is an **abbreviation** for me. It can mean *java utility* or *java utilities*. Same thing happens with `commons-lang`.

**How would you name the package? Why would you choose this name?**

1. `cmns-definitions`
2. `cmns-definition`
3. `cmns-def`

Bonus question: How to name something like `cmns-exceptions`? That's how I name it. Would you name it `cmns-xcpt`?

ËDIT:

I'm throwing in my own thoughts on this in the hope of being either confirmed or contradicted. If you can, please do.

According to what I think, the background reason why you name something is to make it easier to understand what's inside it. Or, according to Peter Kriens, to make it easy to remember and being able to automate processes via patterns. Both are valid arguments.

My reasoning is as follows in terms of pattern:

1) When a substantivation occurs and it's well known in the industry, follow it on your naming.
Eg:
"features" is a case on this. We have a module called cmns-features. Does this mean we have many features on this module? No. It means "the module that implements the "features" file from Apache karaf".
"commons" is a substantivation of "common" well-accepted on the industry. It doesn't mean "many common". It means "Common code".

If I see extr-commons as a module name, I know that it contains common code for extr (in this case extraction), for example.

2) When a quantity of classes inside the module are cooperating to give a distinct "one and one only" meaning to the whole, use singular form to name it.

The majority of modules are included here. If I name something cmns-persistence-jpa, I mean that whatever classes inside cooperate together to provide the jpa implementation of cmns-persistence-api. I don't expect 2 implementations inside it, but actually a myriad of classes that together make one implementation. Crystal clear to me. No?

3) When a grouping of classes is done with the sole purpose of gathering classes by affinity, but the classes don't cooperate together to no purpose, use plural.

Here is the case for example of cmns-definitions (enums used by the whole system).

Alternatively, using an abbreviation circumvents the problem, e.g. cmns-def which can be also "interpreted expanded" by a human reader to cmns-definitions. Many people use also "xxxx-util" meaning xxxx-utilities.

Still a third option can be used to pack things together, using a name that itself means a pluralization. The word "api" comes to mind, but any word that pluralizes something would do, like "pack".

Support to these cases (3) are well-known modules like commons-collections (using the plural) or commons-dbcp (using abbreviation) or commons-lang (again abbreviation) and anything that uses api to pack classes together by affinity.

From apache:
commons-collections -> many powerful data structures that accelerate development of most significant Java applications
commons-lang -> host of helper utilities for the java.lang API
commons-dbcp -> package of several database connection pools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'it is just a name ...'

I find in my long career that these just names can make a tremendous difference in productivity. I do not think it makes a difference if you use *definitions*, *definition*, or *def* as long as you're consistent and use patterns in the name that are easy to remember and can be used to automate processes. A build based on a consistent naming scheme is infinitely easier to work with than a build with "nice human display" names that are ad-hoc and have no discernible pattern.

If you use patterns, names tend to become shorter. Now people working with these names usually spent a lot of time with them. So their readability is not nearly as important as their mnemonic value. It turns out that abbreviations of 3 or 4 characters are surprisingly powerful. One of the reason is they work well is that there is only one possible abbreviation while if you go longer there are many candidates.

Anyway, most import part is the overall consistency. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I believe you're right, a consistent naming scheme is easier to work. I've nailed down what I thought would be a proposition for it and edited my question. If you can, please have a look.

Comment: And I agree also that names are much more important than people normally thing and influence productivity. A name names an abstraction and defines it, and by doing this it influences what this abstraction is supposed to do which in turn affects how you implement it - that's what I think.

Answer (score 0):

`definitions` (or `def` or `definition`) is a bad name because it doesn't have any semantic to a reader. You're in an object oriented world (I suppose) - try to follow its conventions and principles. Modules in Maven should be named after the biggest "abstraction" they contain. "Definition" is a form, not a meaning.

Your question is similar to: "Which class name is better `FileUtilities` or `FileUtils`". Answer: none.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yegor - still, that was not the question. the question is about the use of "s" or not, and use abbreviations or not. Example: cmns-exceptions, cmns-exception or cmns-xcpt , considering that this module contains many exception classes.

Comment: Hmm, I probably was not clear. Maybe if I give another name. cmns-definitions was just an example. For example, take exceptions. All common exceptions of the code are stored in a project called cmns-exceptions. The biggest abstraction there is that the module contains exceptions. It contains many of them, not just one. Now if I name it cmns-exception, it gives me the idea that I have only one there. If I name it cmns-exceptions, it seems to me I'd find exceptions on this module. Now commons-lang uses abbreviation to imply "languages". I'd like to have arguments to use one of them as best.

Comment: The idea of keeping all exceptions in one module is wrong (that's why you're struggling with create a name for them). Exceptions should stay close to the classes that throw them.

Comment: Hi yegor - I don't keep exceptions in one module. The cmns-exceptions has only the foundation classes used by other exceptions in the project.

Comment: There you go, call it `cmns-foundation`. This is the name you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you do with the Definitions and Exceptions is to provide kind of an API for your other modules. So I propose to combine definitions, exceptions and add interfaces to it. Then it makes sense to call it all cmns-api. I normally prefer the singular names as they are shorter but you are free to decide as it is just a name.

Comment: Yes, basically we're spreading the commons all over what would possibly in the future build either something named commons-api or core. At the moment there is:

Comment: - cmns-definitions (contains enums that are exposed to the whole extended project)  
- cmns-exceptions (exceptions used to the whole project)  
- cmns-persistence-api (low-level api to save everything, used by higher level persistence apis)  
- cmns-persistence-jpa (jpa implementation)  
- cmns-structures (DAOs used in the whole project)  
- cmns-util (note the lack of an "s" here due to abbreviation, util -> utilities)  
- cmns-version ( a true non-pluralized name since it contains class(es) that together have just one purpose)

Comment: Your answer for me tends to say "in case of doubt, use a workaround". The "api" is already a pluralization and gives the meaning of the whole thing without becoming confusing. We might have to go to that if there's no consensus on what is to be the naming convention. Thank you.